# PHP Framework for Social Media Monitoring and as well as for Python

Tags: monitoring, social-networking

I'm in the plan to build Social Media Monitoring Application and need the suggestions to choose which framework in the case of PHP and in the case of Python which framework.

As the basic requirement is to 
1) Manage client-specific account networks including Facebook, LinkedIn, MySpace, YouTube, Twitter and many more…
2) Providing the platform for getting engaged with customers, measuring results and monitoring their brand across multiple social media channels at once.
3) Monitoring helps with branding and marketing and can help identify quality control or customer care problems that may have gone unnoticed.

I heard For PHP Framework below are better one:-
i)  ELGG
ii) Yii Framework
iii)    Zend Framework
iv) ATK Framework
v)  SocialEngine
vi) Joomla with JomSocial
vii)    Drupal

And for Python, Django Framework

Can I get some best suggestions which framework I should go ahead for PHP and in case of Python which framework?

Thanks,
Sudhakar

Answer (score 1):

Definitely checkout Laravel http://laravel.com/ It is a very nice framework and worth looking into at the least.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your list symfony2. It is a php framework. there are already plenty of bundles to connect to other apps: http://knpbundles.com/

The official symfony website: symfony.com

There is also a jirafe (build with symfony?) that could maybe be adapted for monitoring SM: http://jirafe.com/

I have also found: www.open-social-media-monitoring.net/ and http://thinkupapp.com/ I have installed both on my server and only thinkup is working properly out of the box. Open Social Media Monitoring has an issue with the installer and I did not have time to attempt debuging it.